# Add Validation to cell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a validation list to Excel that changes via the user's response to a message box.

This is what I have:

```
 If Not Application.Intersect(Me.[B9], ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("New_Project_Code_Request").Range("B9").Value = ""
    strYN = MsgBox(Prompt:="Is this Project Code Request for Cerner HS?", Buttons:=vbExclamation + vbYesNo, Title:="Cerner HS Project Code Request")
    If strYN = vbNo Then
        With Range("B9").Validation
       .Delete
       .Add(Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,Formula1:="=Enterprise!A1:A6")
        End With
    If strYN = vbYes Then Worksheets("Category").Range("E1").Value = 2
End If
```

I keep getting the error

Compile Error:  Expected: =

I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an `end if` after `end with`

Comment: No that doesn't help. It seems to not like the Formula1 parameter

Comment: Remove the brackets: `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,Formula1:="=Enterprise!A1:A6"`

Comment: @Davesexcel ended up I did need the end if after the end with, but removing the parenthesis was needed first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add the opening and closing parenthesis from this line:

```
.Add(Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,Formula1:="=Enterprise!A1:A6")
```

It should read:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,Formula1:="=Enterprise!A1:A6"
```